# How to send data and message to res.send in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I want to send Data and Message together as below REST API response composed with ExpressJS.

**main.js**

```
...
global.RES = require(./response);
...
```

**response.js**

```
exports.SUC_FIND = {
  resCode: '100',
  message: 'Successfully Find Post'
}
```

**API**

```
...
let result = [Post List]

res.send( ? )

// Expected Response in Client
/*
console.log(response.data.resCode) // '100'
console.log(response.data.message) // 'Success ...'
console.log(response.data.result) // [Post List]
*/
...
```

What is the way to do this?

Comment: `res.json({... response, result})`

Comment: use res.send ({}), cannot use the globally registered RES.SUC_FIND. @hoangdv

Comment: put `const response = require(./response);` in api .js file.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly get what you meant but I  believe you ment something like this

**response.js**

```
 var SUC_FIND = {
      resCode: '100',
      message: 'Successfully Find Post'
     }

 module.exports=SUC_FIND;
```

**API**

```
var RES = require(./response);
let result = [Post List]

res.send( {...RES, result} )
```